# CSS first-of-type applying to all

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Having some issues targeting the a div using the CSS :first-of-type and applying the styling to all. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

[Working example here](http://www.web37.co.uk/forum/read.php?5,102,738#msg-738)

```
  .message:first-of-type {
      background: purple;
  }
```

Comment: can you share your full code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want purple background only for first .message use below css. Pseudoclass :first-of-type it's only for type (div, p etc), not class.

```
.message {
    background: purple;
}
.message ~ .message {
    background: none;
}
```